# How should one punctuate the phrase "simply to understand devote yourself"?

Tags: punctuation, acronyms

I found an acronym for the word STUDY online. However, the punctuation looks amiss.

It reads

> Simply — to understand, devote yourself!

But I think the dash makes no sense here. Am I right?

Shouldn't it be

> Simply: to understand, devote yourself!

or even

> Simply... to understand - devote yourself!

Comment: I really hate these sorts of [bacronyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym), but that's a personal preference.  :-)

Comment: _Simply_ has to be seen here as a pragmatic marker relating to the whole of the rest of the maxim. It _can_ be used more restrictively (Is it enough simply/just to phone?), but here 'modifies' the whole statement. It is short for 'To put it simply' or 'Putting it in simple terms', but would look strange with just a comma to offset it. The dash or the colon work better.

Comment: Ah yes, it is a bacronym . .  Hmmm why the hate ;-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Understood, and agreed.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to add to @EdwinAshworth's explanation, if "Simply" were fleshed out a bit more to be more grammatical, you'd no longer have your acronym.  Of course your question was about punctuation - I agree with Edwin's explanation there too, the dash is the best, if you need to use "simply" that way.

Comment: Bacronyms indicate less good English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Agreed, they come off as forced.  .. But it's word-play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*Simply has to be seen here as a pragmatic marker relating to the whole of the rest of the maxim. It can be used more restrictively (Is it enough simply/just to phone?), but here 'modifies' the whole statement. It is short for 'To put it simply' or 'Putting it in simple terms', but would look strange with just a comma to offset it. The dash or the colon work better.*" – Edwin Ashworth

I would go with dash too.